# Ubuntu 14.04 WiFi issues

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have some problems with WiFi on Ubuntu 14.04. My ISP provides me 40Mbps internet but in Ubuntu I can only receive 20Mbps. Same problem I had with OpenSuse distro. On my Windows 7 that problem doesn’t exist, it receives full 40Mbps. Please note that I am not running Virtual Machine, I use dual boot (Ubuntu/Windows 7). Informations about my Wifi card:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
```

Any help or suggestion?

Link to Wireless Script results:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10651558/

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: I have done everything that You asked for. Any suggestion now?

Comment: The wireless chipset only report a maximum available rate of 54 MBit/s for all available access points, which leaves up to 22 Mbit/s net under good conditions, even though the spec declares a support for 300 Mbit/s. I can't find anything on why this is. This may be fixed in a newer version of the `ath9k` driver, so you may want to try a newer kernel. See https://askubuntu.com/a/598934/175814 for instructions.

Comment: Neither Kernel update couldnt solve the problem :(...

Comment: It doesn't look like a client side issue.  The local side can do up to 300 Mbps but for some or other reason the router itself is only advertising 56 Mbps...  Is there a way to upgrade the router's firmware?