# Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.19 Kernel Wants to Update to 3.16

Tags: kernel, software-installation, uninstall

I recently updated my kernel to 3.19.0 to resolve some issues with a Dell XPS 9394 ('15), and things are mostly working well, though now software update looks like it wants to download and install headers and images for kernel 3.16. How do I make sure SU is pulling updates for the 3.19 kernel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you upgrade to Linux 3.19?

Comment: Just because you have _installed_ 3.19, have you confirmed that you are actually booted into this kernel? Please check the output of `uname -r`.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I'm running 3.19

Comment: I upgraded the kernal by manually downloading the debs from kernel.org mainline.

Comment: @wardrobe why not install the officially supported Ubuntu 14.04 3.19 kernel as described here http://askubuntu.com/questions/598483

Answer (score 4):

First things first. How did you install kernel 3.19? As you're running a LTS release, the recommended way to install new kernels is by [Hardware Enablement](https://askubuntu.com/q/248914/65926). Kernel 3.19 is available in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories. Make sure you have it installed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Now, reboot the computer to load the new kernel. Make sure it is running:

```
uname -r
```

The above command should return something like `3.19.0-20-generic`. Now you can remove older kernels. Start with:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic linux-image-generic-lts-utopic linux-signed-generic linux-signed-generic-lts-utopic
```

The above should remove the kernel meta packages which install updates for kernels 3.13 and 3.16. At this point, newer releases for kernels 3.13 and 3.16 will not be offered anymore, but the (possible) already installed kernels may receive updates. List the installed kernel packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep -E "linux-(generic|headers|image|signed)" | colrm 80
```

If you see any package with version lower than 3.19, remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge <package name 1> <package name 2> ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I installed the new kernel successfully but didn't want to remove the older ones in case I needed to boot with them via recovery. Will purging these packages prevent me from doing that?

Comment: @wardrobe The first `apt-get purge` **probably** will not remove the kernels. You could run it then look at the list of packages that will be removed. If some package like linux-image-3.XX.0-YY-generic will be removed you could just cancel (Ctrl+C) the operation.