# Wine not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine

I have been facing problems trying to run Wine on my system. I uninstalled it just in case there were some corruption in the installation, and reinstalled it, but it still doesn't work. The program won't just start. There is no pop up window appearing notifying me of any error that might be there, so I have no idea why this is happening. Anything I can do here to get things back up and running? Or is there any substitute to Wine for running Windows programs?

Comment: Try opening a terminal with Ctrl + T and type 'winecfg' to see if the configuration window will open. If it does, try to run an exe file in the terminal with 'wine <file name>'. You can edit your question with the output if there are any error messages

Comment: wine itself is a command line programm, so there should be no pop-up. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have the same problem after a system update. I was running wine 1.6. I tried to move to 1.7 but still go nothing.  Looking at a list of which files were updated, I think that a possible culprit is linux-libc-dev (in my case amd64 from 3.13.0-58.97 to  3.13.0-59.98). I have to look if it is possible to roll back to the previous version.

Comment: Tried installing the previous version of linux-libc-dev and got a different crash. Initially I had a wineserver crash now it was a wine64-preloader crash. Things continued evolving with other roll backs but the system became instable and I started to break dependencies. I gave up and brought the system back to the latest version. I guess (I hope) that waiting a couple of days for a new update might fix this issue.

Comment: Here's a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/653732/wine-segfault-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @Bruni: I am talking about system error messages. And I am basically trying to run Windows programs using Wine, which isn't happening.

Comment: @rpsml: Did you happen to get a red warning notification  telling you that your update system was 'outdated', lately? Strange thing is, I got that notification only once. The system has updated itself a couple of times since then. Anyway, from my experience, that usually means that an **upgrade** is in order. My system has become unusually slow and stuff.  So I am thinking the Wine problem is part of a greater malady.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Zilvador Ah, now I see some errors. `winecfg` gives this: `err:process:start_wineboot failed to start wineboot, err 1359
err:winecfg:WinMain failed to restart 64-bit L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winecfg.exe", err 1359`
Pop up message accompanying: http://i61.tinypic.com/whzlg9.png
`$  wine --version`-->
`wine-1.6.2`

Comment: Kernel version 3.13.0-59 might be the problem then, @jrudolph ? I'm a bit reluctant to go back to a previous kernel version.

Comment: When reinstalling wine, did you also remove the ~/.wine directory? Regarding trying another kernel version, if you enter grub and enter the advanced options menu, you can easily try out a previous Ubuntu kernel version, since it is most likely still installed next to the new one.

Comment: @UserName I do not have any particular problems with my installation (I run the xubuntu version). The problem arrived after a regular kernel update. I am holding any updates on other machines until this is fixed.

Comment: @Zilvador No, the /.wine directory is still there. I (reluctantly) did use the previous kernel version, and now I am getting the errors rpsml reported. The thing is, I am getting both preloader and wineserver errors on the current kernel (I switched back to the newer one).

Comment: Additionally, `You have some obsolete packages installed. Please upgrade and check if the problem still occurs: dh-python, ghostscript, iproute2, libgs9, libgs9-common, libgudev-1.0-0, passwd`

Comment: My current kernel version is 3.13.0-59 and I can't run wine in it. I booted with my previous version (3.13.0-52) and wine worked fine.

Comment: @UserName Not enough rep to post an answer, but I got a work around and a solution. The work around, as proposed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1479040) is to start the server on the command line. It complains but the program starts: `wineserver;sleep 1;wine <program name>`.  The "solution" was to upgrade the kernel to version 3.19. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/598483/how-can-i-use-kernel-3-19-in-14-04-now/628362#628362) the how-to.

Comment: @rpsml I see. The thing is, I had a kernel update again today, and Wine has been running pretty fine since. So I guess your initial ploy of waiting and watching was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed today with the latest kernel update 3.13.0-61

Comment: For those reading: see also the related question on [this Wine + kernel issue](http://askubuntu.com/q/654094/38585) for further links and suggestions.