# Wine segfault on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine

```
$ wine --version
wine-1.7.47-161-g1a0c4ef

$ winecfg
syslog: kernel: [33279.238873] wineserver[9087]: segfault at eeb102d0 ip 00000000eeb102d0 sp 0000000052879ac0 error 14 in ld-2.19.so[7fb3eeb0f000+23000]

$ wine prog.exe
syslog: kernel: [33554.031996] wineserver[9173]: segfault at a31c12d0 ip 00000000a31c12d0 sp 00000000a4fdfbf0 error 14 in ld-2.19.so[7f37a31c0000+23000]
```

Comment: Have you changed anything at all in Wine or installed anything, or is it just doing this right after a fresh install?

Comment: No, it happened after today's update.

Comment: can you rollback the install?

Answer (score 5):

I booted the previous kernel (3.13.0-58-generic) and it works again.  3.13.0-59 fails for me.

Comment: I filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1479040

Comment: It did not help. When I enter the login / password, I was again taken to the lightdm.
Apparently this is due to the ATI driver (proprietary).

Answer (score 4):

Solved. Today updated the kernel (3.13.0-61), and all was fine.

Answer (score 3):

Install newer 3.19.0-25 kernel. And wine 1.6 works again!

see this post [How can I use Kernel 3.19 in 14.04 now?](https://askubuntu.com/a/628362)

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`

Comment: +1 I don't get the downvote. This is the solution that I chose. And it works.

Comment: @rpsml If this answer works for you then don't forget to tick ☑ on left of this answer and up-vote it.

Comment: @mudit-kapil I did upvote the answer (hence the +1 preceeding my comment). But I did not ask the question, so I cannot accept it...

Comment: @rpsml do it on the ^  mark left on the answer not in comments

Comment: @mudit-kapil That is exactly what I did (and then pointed out in my comment that I upvoted it).

Comment: @rpsml You dint not upvoted it correctly It is my vote that is reflecting

Comment: @mudit-kapil Yes I did. When I upvoted it had been previously downvoted. Hence my surprised comment "I don't get the downvote". BTW, you should have enough rep to see the number of +'s and -'s (assuming that askubuntu has the same policy of other stackexchange sites)...

Answer (score 3):

Running a wineserver instance manually seems to help. Run `wineserver -p` before trying to run a program with wine.

**UPDATE: changing the working directory doesn't help reproducibly but running wineserver manually does.**

Comment: No, same error: kernel: [  110.463946] wineserver[3687]: segfault at c9f4d2d0 ip 00000000c9f4d2d0 sp 000000003053f5c0 error 14 in ld-2.19.so[7f71c9f4c000+23000]

Comment: This was confirmed to help in the launchpad ticket and also going back to the old kernel. So, maybe you have a different variation of the problem?

Comment: wineserver;sleep 1 is work. ps ax | grep wine
22434 ?        Ss     0:00 wineserver

Comment: wineserver;sleep 1;wine prog.exe : kernel: [24528.776922] wine64-preloade[22450]: segfault at 7c872d40 ip 000000007c40000c sp 000000007c872d40 error 6 in wine64-preloader[7c400000+3000]

Comment: Have you tried using the `-p` flag? Otherwise, it may have already shut down again.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but all the same (

Comment: Can confirm. This solution worked for me!