# Dell XPS 15 (2017) Ubuntu 16.04 Freezes

Tags: 16.04, dell

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a new partition to dual boot with Windows 10.

I have a Dell XPS 15 (i7 7th Gen).  I constantly get screen freezes at random intervals.  I have seen the c-state bug and have added the necessary extension to grub to avoid this.

I do not know how to proceed from here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I'm in the same situation, have you found any other solution beyond downgrading the kernel?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with my Dell XPS 15. 
The solution for me was to **downgrade my kernel** from 4.10 to 4.8. 
[Instructions on downgrading kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654094/how-to-roll-back-or-downgrade-kernel-on-14-04-re-wine-stopped-working). 
I used the 4.8.0 kernel, downloaded from [Site for downloading old kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)