# GRUB fails to load, dual booting Win 7 and Ubuntu 18.04 (Blinking cursor, rescue mode fails )

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I dual boot Win 7 and Ubuntu 18.04. I use Windows BCD as my primary bootloader which lets me select my Ubuntu partition. Things were working fine a couple of weeks ago and I did apt-get upgrade.

Now if I select my Ubuntu parition all I get is a blinking cursor. I tried going into GRUB rescue mode by holding shift. Now I get the word GRUB and a blinking cursor but I can't type anything. I can boot into Win 7 fine. I've done a little research and it may be a kernel issue, perhaps caused by the last update.

Is it possible to fix without using boot repair?

Thanks

Comment: use a livedisk to access the system and post the output of `jouralctl`, and `dmesg`

Comment: [dmesg uploaded here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WMXVp3rvQX/)  And here's  [journalctl](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QbdMVQ9J3W/)

Comment: [GRUB config](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8fDgRTyB3V/) if it helps

Comment: When you're in the livedisk try mounting the system and downgrading the kernl

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/654094/how-to-roll-back-or-downgrade-kernel-on-14-04-re-wine-stopped-working

Comment: I tried rolling back the kernel, not sure if I did it correctly. Whatever I did, it still doesn't boot. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JwDVMgQF8z/