# dist-upgrade, showing diffrent kernel updated

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, 14.10

Today I ran

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Nothing strange there, however, I noticed this line

```
Setting up linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.51.42) ...
```

The problem here is that I am not running `utopic` I am running `Trusty`.

So, why was a kernel labelled `utopic` updated on a `trusty` system ? can anyone please explain ? There are no other references to this in my terminal output, just the one line and I did not install it (fresh install one week ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not running `utopic`, but LTS Ubuntu versions have an option to install kernels from the newer releases.

`linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` is a meta package that pulls 3.16 major kernel versions.

In Ubuntu 14.04.2 the `utopic` kernel comes by default.

You can read about [HWE Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

So everything is OK with your system. If you remove `linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` package, your kernel 3.16 will not get upgrades.

You can also install 3.19 kernel by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

And soon the 4.2 `wily` kernel will appear as an option for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/598483/how-can-i-use-kernel-3-19-in-14-04-now

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at output of `apt-get show linux-image-generic-lts-trusty`  and `linux-image-generic-lts-vivid` you can see something curious:

```
xieerqi@eagle:~$ apt-cache show linux-image-generic-lts-vivid | grep -i version
Version: 3.19.0.31.18
Version: 3.19.0.30.17

xieerqi@eagle:~$ apt-cache show linux-image-generic-lts-trusty | grep -i version 
Version: 3.13.0.66.72
Version: 3.13.0.24.28
```

In addition, note what [release notes say](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes):

> By default, the 14.04.3 point release will ship with a newer 3.19 Linux kernel from Ubuntu 15.04, and a matching X.org stack

So when you upgraded, the system chose by version, which one is the latest available lts kernel.

Comment: The answer is obvious. `lts-vivid` is 3.19 because kernel 3.19 is in the `vivid` release.

Comment: @Pilot6 I removed that part. You're right, that's kind of obvious