# Any plans to update Ubuntu 140.04 Kernel beyond 3.16.0-34-generic

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates

As per the title.  I'm having issues with my wireless network, and from what I've read, these have been addressed in more recent releases.

Answer (score 0):

Latest available Ubuntu 14.04  is 14.04.03 and it comes with kernel version 3.19. If you already have an older version, you can install new kernel version this way:

[How can I use Kernel 3.19 in 14.04 now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598483/how-can-i-use-kernel-3-19-in-14-04-now)